# How to find highest key in JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

An API I'm working with is returning poorly structured data like this:

```
{
    "scsi0": "vm-101-disk-1.qcow2,size=32G",
    "scsi1": "vm-101-disk-2.qcow2,size=32G",
    "scsi2": "vm-101-disk-3.qcow2,size=32G"
}
```

As you can see, instead of having a `scsi` object with then contains the `0, 1, 2` key/value pairs, I just have the keys named like that.

In JavaScript, how can I search for the highest `scsi` value which in that case would be `2`?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Fix the API to return what you need.

Comment: So far I've tried `JSON.stringify(stuff).lastIndexOf("scsi")` but I'm not confident in this solution since if the order of the items change for any reason the result won't be as expected

Comment: @KoshVery wish I could fix the API but it's not under my control :(

Comment: If your object is always structured like the way you have shown, then `Object.keys(stuff).length - 1` will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.keys()` is a good place to start for jobs like this. How about something like this?

```js
var data = {
  "scsi0": "vm-101-disk-1.qcow2,size=32G",
  "scsi1": "vm-101-disk-2.qcow2,size=32G",
  "scsi2": "vm-101-disk-3.qcow2,size=32G"
};

// get keys of data
var keys = Object.keys(data);

// get array of number values
var numbers = keys.map(function(key) {
  // strip text out of keys, parse as integers
  return parseInt(key.replace(/\D/g, '') || 0);
})

// get the largest number in the array
var highest = Math.max.apply(null, numbers);

// build the data key with this number
var key = "scsi" + highest;

// get the data pertaining to the key
var final = data[key];

// log the result
console.log(final);
```

Comment: I've added a small check for `key.startsWith("scsi")` just in case something else (e.g. `whatever99`) is returned by the API for some reason. Accepting this as it's the most readable solution

Answer (score 2):

You could use a collator to get a `compare` function that takes such embedded numbers into account:

```js
const data = {
    "scsi0": "vm-101-disk-1.qcow2,size=32G",
    "scsi11": "vm-101-disk-2.qcow2,size=32G",
    "scsi2": "vm-101-disk-3.qcow2,size=32G"
};

const cmp = (new Intl.Collator(undefined, {numeric: true})).compare;
const max = Object.keys(data).reduce((a, b) => cmp(a, b) > 0 ? a : b);

console.log(max)
```

Comment: Wow! Beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` on `keys` of your object:

```js
var  o = {
    "scsi0": "vm-101-disk-1.qcow2,size=32G",
    "scsi11": "vm-101-disk-2.qcow2,size=32G",
    "scsi2": "vm-101-disk-3.qcow2,size=32G"
};


var max = Object.keys(o).reduce((m, k) => +m.replace(/\D/g, '') > +k.replace(/\D/g, '') ? m : m = k);

console.log(max, +max.replace(/\D/g, ''))
```

Comment: Fails if you add key `scsi11`

Comment: @charlietfl, my bad! Fixed.